# Propel - Joining the same table multiple times and grouping

Tags: php, join, grouping, propel

I'm writing a report with Propel and need to join the *same table* multiple times in order to get different stats for different date ranges using the same data.

The issue appears to be that propel ignores multiple `->leftJoin()` calls on a query. I think I need to alias each join so they can be treated individually but I can't find a way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try addJoin()

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->addJoin(array(Table1Peer::ID,), array(Table2Peer::Table1Peer_ID,), Criteria::LEFT_JOIN);
```

Looks like you can also alias:

```
$c->addJoin(TablePeer::alias("alias1", TablePeer::PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN), TablePeer::PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN);
```

With the ability to alias and pass in arrays it seems you should be able to do multi-joins to the same table.

Comment: Your aliasing example looks as if it may work. might not get chance to give it a proper try until tomorrow - will let you know :) thanks

Comment: This was over a year ago now, I obviously forgot to accept your answer but I vaguely remember that it worked. It's certainly not a problem any more anyway :)

Comment: Ahhh glad to hear. Just curious, are you still using propel, or did you move to a different orm?

Comment: The project in question still uses Propel and it would probably be a bit of a nightmare to rip it out and move to a different ORM. I do find Propel infuriating at times, but that's probably down to user error in reality. I am a Doctrine fan though and not had chance to play with Doctrine 2 properly so if I was to change, that would be the way I would go.

Comment: Doctrine 2 has [a lot of issues though](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/limitations-and-known-issues.html) that I ran into when I tried to use it.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that this answer did not work for me. I need to join the same table to itself more than once and it does not work.

Comment: @NobleUplift: Doctrine doesn't use the posted syntax.

Comment: Ah, sorry. My comments were posted 20 minutes apart but now it looks like they were posted together. On first read-through, I wanted to point out the flaws in Doctrine that I ran into fast (mainly with foreign keys). Second, I tested this code in Propel and it did not work. I created [a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203960/how-do-i-join-a-table-to-itself-multiple-times-in-propel?lq=1) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can just add **"RelatedBy"** relationship methods ...

Ex.:

```
ItemQuery::create()
->leftJoinItemRelatedByCodItemFather( 'Child' )
    ->addAsColumn( 'ChildName', "Child.name" )
->find() ;
```

I Always prefer to use auto generated Propel Methods =D